# redirect() doesn't work in codeigniter 3.0 and php 7.2.3 lampp server

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, codeigniter-3, lampp

routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'login';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'file','form','html');
```

controller: login.php

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        if ($this->auth->login($login, $password, $remember_me)) {
              //echo site_url().'dashboard/index';
              //print_r($this->session->userdata());
              //die;
              redirect(site_url().'dashboard/index');
              //header('Location: /someurl.php');
              //$this->load->view('template/index');
        } else {
        $this->data['error_message'] = 'The username or password you entered is incorrect.';
        }
}
```

This code is working properly in php-5.6 xampp server (os:windows).

But it doesn't work in php-7.2.3 lampp server (os:ubuntu).

`login()` method sets session data and `returns true`. But `redirect()` method can't redirect. When i set `redirect('https://facebook.com')` then it works.

What is difference between xampp and lampp? Why redirect method doesn't work in php-7.2.3 lampp server (ubuntu)?

Comment: check if there's any space or empty line in your view file after php closing tag, there are some issues related with this

Comment: if i use die method in targeted file after rendering vew. result is same

Comment: Im not familiair with this but cant you just use header to redirect?

Comment: I see you have some test code regarding your redirect string. What did you get for that. What happens when you paste it direct into a browser? Might be site_url() aint configured correctly.